# Does TBA become MBS after pool is announced?

Tags: mbs

Is TBA still called TBA after the pool is announced? Can it be said that TBAs are still traded after the announcement or are all those trades effectively in MBS? I am looking to understand market for both instruments a bit better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pools to be delivered in a TBA trade are identified no later than 3pm two business days prior to the settlement date ("48-hour day"). Essentially, all TBA pricing is rolled from this settlement date to the new front month (settlement date) by 48-hour day. For a solid introduction to MBS TBA trading (and the closely-related Specified Pool Market), see Section 3 in [TBA Trading and Liquidity in the Agency MBS Market](https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/epr/2013/1212vick.html).

To the extent that TBA trading for a specific settlement date does take place after its 48-hour day, it is most likely in the context of a "fail". This is a complex topic but see [Understanding Settlement Fails in Agency MBS](https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/microsites/tmpg/files/tmpg_04292011.pdf) for an introduction.

Regarding nomenclature, both TBAs and Specified Pools are specific types of mortgage-backed securities (MBS), hopefully the first paper should clear up some of these distinctions.